# Macports - php5-mysql 5.3.6 requires PHP 5.3.6 but you have PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, mysql, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I am trying to set up a old PHP version using Macports on Snow Leopard. I have installed `sudo port install php52 +apache2 +mysql5-server` with no problem when I then try to install php5-mysql I get the following error.

```
Error: php5-mysql 5.3.6 requires PHP 5.3.6 but you have PHP 5.2.17.
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: incompatible PHP installation
Log for php5-mysql is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_php_php5-mysql/main.log
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

I have tried to search the MacPorts help although this has not been very helpful to me in finding anything that relates to my problem.

Comment: Well, the `php5-mysql` package is obviously targeted at the current version of PHP, you will need to find an older version to go with the older PHP variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an older version of php5-mysql that works with your PHP version, which is 5.2.17. Otherwise you will always run into this problem.

This is also known as a package dependency. If you can not fullfil a dependency, the package can not be installed (well it probably could, but then it would not run, so the package manager refuses you to install that).

From the [changelog of the mysqli package](https://trac.macports.org/log/trunk/dports/php/php5-mysql/Portfile) it does not look like that 5.2 is supported, but according to linked information it might have been in some older package.